# Memoir way of vertically align subfigures

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, memoir, subfloats

When having two subfigures of different size, is there a way to vertically align them?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centerfloat
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics[height = 2cm]{example-image-duck}}~%
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
    \caption{The two figures should be vertically aligned}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: g]
I'd like the horisontal lines in the two figures to line up.
is there some cool memoir way to do this?

Comment: You might want to specify where (a) should go when that image is vcentered.

Comment: @daleif I thought this was clear (but perhaps not): I'd like the horisontal lines in the two figures to line up. By horisontal line, I mean the center line (the horisontal line going through the duck)

Comment: That is clear enough, but where should the subcation `(a)` go? right below the image or on the same line as `(b)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is updated:

[image: Output]
[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}% Takes half the text width (left to center)
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height = 2cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{A long caption of the subcaption of the left subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}% Takes half the text width, (other half center to right)
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{
            A long caption of the subcaption of the right subfigure copied and 
            pasted twice a long caption of the subcaption of the right subfigure
        }
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Overall Overall Overall Overall Overall Overall Overall Overall caption}
\end{figure}

%----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}% Takes half the text width (left to center)
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height = 2cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{A long caption of the subcaption of the left subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}% Takes half the text width, (other half center to right)
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{
            A long caption of the subcaption of the right subfigure copied and 
            pasted twice a long caption of the subcaption of the right subfigure
        }
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Overall Overall Overall Overall Overall Overall Overall Overall caption}
\end{figure}

%----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.7\textwidth}% Takes half the text width (left to center)
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height = 2cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{A long caption of the subcaption of the left subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.2\textwidth}% Takes half the text width, (other half center to right)
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{A long caption of the subcaption of the right subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Overall Overall Overall Overall Overall Overall Overall Overall caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Previous answer:**

You can use the `graphbox` package which allows you to specify the align type you would like. You can use `align = t` for top alignment, `align = c` for center or `align = b` for bottom.

[image: Old Output]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphbox}   % Need this!
\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centerfloat
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics[height = 1cm, align = t]{example-image-a}}
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics[height = 2cm, align = t]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{The two figures should be vertically aligned (top)}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{-3cm}
\begin{figure}
    \centerfloat
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics[height = 1cm, align = c]{example-image-a}}
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics[height = 2cm, align = c]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{The two figures should be vertically aligned (center)}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{-3cm}
\begin{figure}
    \centerfloat
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics[height = 1cm, align = b]{example-image-a}}
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics[height = 2cm, align = b]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{The two figures should be vertically aligned (bottom)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there no way to align center? If I want the horizontal lines of my example figures to lign up??? And keep the captions starting at the same height??

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: can you move the legend down, so the legend is aligned with the other legends??

Comment: You mean the caption?

Comment: yes, Sorry. Thanks for the answer. It was very helpfull

Comment: Check out the updated answer again.

Comment: but the caption is still not moved down when you use `align = t`